# python simhash doesn't work on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, simhash

I have the same setup and code on mac for running simhash, it works.

But when I run it on Ubuntu, it complaints the implementation of simhash itself has the bug.

Have you encountered such problem?

objs = [(str(k), Simhash(v)) for k, v in index_data.items()]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simhash-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/simhash/**init**.py", line 30, in **init**
    self.build_by_text(unicode(value))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 34: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Ubuntu just released a new LTS - are you on that version? It might be better to move this question to askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you, that str(k) can't be correctly decoded. Since I don't know where the data is coming from and what it actually is, I can just say that something like

```
str(k).decode('cp850')
```

or

```
Simhash(v.decode('cp850'))
```

might help. Assuming the string is in cp850. At least I can do a `'\xf6'.decode('cp850')`.

And since that seems to be a problem within the module, check, that the string that is used is properly decoded beforehand.

Comment: I don't know where exactly the problem is, but the traceback tells us, that it's an encoding-error. The string has it's encoding (UTF-8, cp850 etc.), and that's not being handled well by Simhash. So if possible, the string has to be converted to unicode before Simhashing it.